# Ionic Stencil: Extending default components

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, stenciljs, stencil-component

I need to make certain changes in the behavior of some of the ionic components.

It was easy enough with Ionic 3 and angular components, but now that we're migrating to Ionic 4, I'm finding it more challenging to alter the default web components in `@ionic/core`.

I have created a new stencil components project and added the npm package for `@ionic/core`. I tired extending the `datetime` component and found that the web components cannot have super classes.

So I copied over the entire folder for the datetime component from the Ionic source to my project and changed only the folder name and the class name. So it's `MyDatetime` class in `my-datetime` folder.

Trying `npm run build` on the project, it fails with a whole bunch of sass errors.

Here's how they look like:

```
[ ERROR ]  sass error: src/components/my-datetime/datetime.ios.scss:1:9
           Can't find stylesheet to import.

      L1:  @import "./datetime";


[ ERROR ]  sass error: node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/collection/components/tab-bar/tab-bar.ios.scss:207:14
           expected selector.


[ ERROR ]  sass error: node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/collection/components/item/item.ios.scss:207:14
           expected selector.

    L207:  // .label-ios + ion-textarea .native-textarea,
    L208:  // .label-ios + .input + .cloned-input {
```

The imported sass file that it says it cannot find (`./datetime`) is of course existing in the same folder.

Could someone please hint on what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: I recently got the same "expected selector." errors while updating Stencil on an existing project. In my case it was because of incompatible versions of `@stencil/core` and `@stencil/sass`. What versions are you using?

Comment: @Thomas They're both 6.9.0

Comment: @Vahid , did you figure out ?

Comment: @Chilipote Unfortunately not. I moved back to using angular components for this project.