# Ionic 4 infinite-scroll initial scroll position

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to make a dual infinite scroll case when new items are added as the user scrolls either all the way up or all the way down.

```
<ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="scrolledUp($event)" position="top">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>

<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
         <!-- item content -->
    <ion-item>
</ion-list>

<ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="scrolledDown($event)"  position="bottom">
   <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

The problem is that the list opens initially at the bottom. Of course I can scrollIntoView the first item on `ionViewDidEnter` but it wouldn't look nice and would confuse the users.

I noticed it's the one with `position=top` that is responsible for the initial position at the bottom.

Is there a way to set the initial scroll position for the `ion-infinite-scroll` without having to explicitly scroll the list to top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I initially suspected the [infinite scroll component](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/components/infinite-scroll/infinite-scroll.tsx) does force a scroll to bottom if position is set to top. It occurs in the `componentDidLoad` method as shown below:

> ```
>  async componentDidLoad() {
>     const contentEl = this.el.closest('ion-content');
>     if (contentEl) {
>       await contentEl.componentOnReady();
>       this.scrollEl = await contentEl.getScrollElement();
>     }
>     this.thresholdChanged();
>     this.disabledChanged();
>     if (this.position === 'top') {
>       writeTask(() => {
>         if (this.scrollEl) {
>           this.scrollEl.scrollTop = this.scrollEl.scrollHeight - this.scrollEl.clientHeight;
>         }
>       });
>     }
>   }
> ```

As the component provides no means to intervene in this behavior and [without an option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56633505/ionic-stencil-extending-default-components) to extend or otherwise customize the default stencil components, I turned to a somewhat hacky way to achieve the desired behavior.

Therefore, you first need to remove the `position=top` part from the `ion-infinite-scroll` declaration in your view so that the scroll part of the above code won't trigger. You would also provide a name for the `ion-infinite-scroll` so that it can be referenced from your page class.

```
<ion-infinite-scroll #top (ionInfinite)="scrolledUp($event)">
```

Then you make a reference to `#top` above in your page.

```
  @ViewChild('top') topScroller;
```

Then in the `ionViewDidEnter` life cycle hook, you can set the position for the scroller as top.

```
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.topScroller.position = 'top';
  }, 200);
```

It has to be in a time out because the topScroller variable is still not assigned when `ionViewDidEnter` is called and the next life cycle hook is `ionViewWillLeave` which won't be that useful for our purpose.